# Dismiss async task after sometime

Tags: java, android, timeout, android-asynctask

hey guys
i want to dismiss my async task after 60 seconds i.e, if the server is taking much time to respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)

Comment: well i found get(time , unit) more interesting than cancel...  but i am getting problem in implementing get(time , unit) i am using following code in my doInBackground                                  get(60000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)

Comment: please let me know how can i implement the above in doInBackground